# Using BeautifulSoup to extract <span> WITH tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How can I properly extract the value of a `<span>` WITH the `<br/>` tags?

i.e.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = '<span id="spamANDeggs">This is<br/>what<br/>I want. WITH the <br/> tags.</span>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text)

text_wanted = soup.find('span',{'id':'spamANDeggs'}).GetText(including<br/>...)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `decode_contents()` method just like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = '<span id="spamANDeggs">This is<br/>what<br/>I want. WITH the <br/> tags.</span>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text)
text_wanted = soup.find('span', {'id': 'spamANDeggs'}).decode_contents(formatter="html")
```

Now `text_wanted` equals `"This is<br/>what<br/>I want. WITH the <br/> tags."`